# Laravel: Split model across two tables

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a model `titles`

My `titles` DB table is getting rather large 100,000+ rows of data.

What is the best way to create a new `titles2` table and join it with the `titles` table so that they can both be the same `titles` model?

Also if I finish adding rows to `titles` at id 100,000 should i start incrementing `titles2` at id 100,001 to that the ids will always be unique?

Comment: Why you want to separate it into 2 tables? If you are worrying about performance? Try creating index for the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column ex. source to differentiate these two table records. This way you can make sure that there's no way we will run into the problem of mixing these two datasets.

However for conveniency, we still want to make sure the id itself is unique across different dataset, which requires you not to use auto-increment for id field, because you'll gonna be the one to handle the id generation.

Some of the issues that I run into includes using the following line to update or insert the record,

```
$db->table('users')->insert($record);
```

instead of

```
User::create($record); // assume you are using auto-increment ids
```